# Get Random integer value C#

Tags: c#, random

Why using the method `RandomBool()`, I always get 1? Please, help fix the second method.

```
static class Tools
{
    public static int RandomNumber(int end)
    {
        var rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        return rand.Next(0, end);
    }

    public static bool RandomBool()
    {
        if(RandomNumber(1) == 0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the random class, Second parameter is **exclusive** upper bound

Comment: Obbligatory reference: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Two errors: don't reinizialize Random every time. Otherwise you will reinitialize it with the same seed if the function is called twice in the same millisecond. Put `rand` in a static variable and live happy. And then as written by others, `RandomNumber(2) `

Comment: The way you create instances of `Random` will lead to repeated values if you call it in quick succession (within a few milliseconds). But simply putting it in a static variable, like @xanatos suggests isn't a good idea either since it's not threadsafe.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are right... then you can mark it with `[ThreadStatic]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
if(RandomNumber(2) == 0)
```

This includes 0 and 1, but excludes 2 as Random excludes the upper bounds.

Alternatively change `return rand.Next(0, end);` to `return rand.Next(0, end + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
 if(RandomNumber(2) == 0)  // <= Correction ; RandomNumber(2) will Return 0 OR 1
            return true;
  else 
            return false;
```

Random.Next Method : ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx))

When you call it as this, `Random.Next(MinValue,MaxValue)` , following rule apply

> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue. The range of return values includes minValue **but not maxValue**.

In your case you used  as `Min = 0` and `Max =1`, which would always return `0`.